# Получение исторического значения котировок единым значением, а не таблицей

Tags: google-spreadsheet

При использовании формулы в ячейке:

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE($O$32, "price",TODAY()-365*5,TODAY()-365*5+1)
```

Получаем значение цены акции с тикером в ячейке О32 пять лет назад. Но получаем это в виде таблицы с заголовком:

> Date | Close
>
> 9/30/2014 16:00:00 | 105

Как в таком случае получить единое значение 105, которое я мог бы использовать в формуле, единым запросом? Может какой-нибудь `to_table(...).cell[2,2].value`, или вроде того. Или вовсе другую формулу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вся таблица в одной ячейке, заменяем последний символ-разделитель на множество пробелов, получаем правую часть текста и удаляем лишние пробелы:

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(O32,"|",REPT(" ",50)),50))
```

Но *GOOGLEFINANCE* возвращает таблицу - массив, размещенный в нескольких ячейках.
Из массива получить нужное значение по индексу:

```
=ИНДЕКС(массив,строка,столбец)
```

Или полная формула:

```
=INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE($E$1, "price",TODAY()-365*5,TODAY()-365*5+1),2,2)
```

Comment: А вы точно поняли вопрос? Не похоже, что это может так сработать. На всякий случай приведу ссылку на справку по GOOGLEFINANCE. https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?hl=ru На странице справки сразу Ctrl+F и вводим "Historical market data". Одна формула для вывода сразу нескольких ячеек. Могу предположить, что запрос присылает ответ одной строкой с разделителем "|", но у меня что-то ваша формула не применилась.. Выводит просто Date (то есть левую верхнюю ячейку)

Comment: В формуле сделайте ссылку на нужную ячейку.

Comment: Да, я безусловно, сразу понял, что O32 нужно заменить на ту, где у меня введена формула, получающая табличку, ведь в O32 лежит только тикер (например, "T"). Но, как я сказал, формула `=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(N33,"|",REPT(" ",50)),50))` возвращает единственное слово Date

Comment: Не на ту, где введена формула, а на ту ячейку, в которую выводится нужная часть таблицы. Если и это не сработает, покажите ссылку на таблицу с проблемой.  Работаю с Excel, не знаю тонкостей этой функции.

Comment: Я тут погуглил и нагуглил понятие массива в гугл-таблица. Например, введите формулу `={1,2;3,4}` и она заполнит сразу 4 ячейки, т.к. вы ввели двухмерный массив. GOOGLEFINANCE возвращает такой же двухмерный массив. И вот нужно, судя по всему, получать конкретный элемент массива. Какой-нибудь `={1,2;3,4}[2,2]` например (не рабочий пример).

Comment: Покажите ссылку на таблицу с примером (где можно поиграться с функцией)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RuzMa6tSSOPAvL6JoyoOsjw0UHfZiNtwoY1x59r_PFA/edit?usp=sharing
Хотя, там ничего нового же =)

Comment: Давно бы так :) Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Шикардос) А я уже что только не перепробовал. ROW, VALUE, как-то адресацию после знака "!". А оказывается INDEX. Нагуглить по таким тегам как-то тоже не получалось. Благодарю-съ